# Acceleration vs. Velocity

Tags: acceleration, velocity

Since acceleration is a change in velocity or a change in direction how can in reality velocity exist since a straight line does not exist except in Euclidean geometry? Any movement from one point to another must have some change in direction.

Comment: Physics is not euclidean geometry or any other kind of mathematics. It's an empirical description of nature.

Comment: If I were to empirically measure the movement of an object from one point to another and had sensitive enough equipment would I not find a deviation in direction? I think velocity is something that cannot exist by itself. When its said that an electron's dimension's might be a geometric point one wonders like Boscovich. Empirical means the taking of data and fitting it to equations. Thats why I think physics is applied mathematics. It would seem to me therefore that's why the SToR is a subset of the GToR.

Comment: Of course you would deviations and empiricism is perfectly fine with that. That's why I said that physics is not math. It doesn't despair when things are not "ideal" but it embraces whatever it finds. My first theoretical physics professor began his lecture series with an announcement. He explained that "Physics is the art of approximation" and that whoever doesn't feel comfortable with that should leave the room now because they would be wasting their time on a subject that they would never like. That's the simple way of summing up physical ontology: it looks for laws that are "good enough"!

Comment: Makes sense and yet they claim to have one photon or one electron instead of approx. one. Confusing for me. Seems like the deviations ought to be due to accuracy of the measuring equipment and method and that if the input to the equation is exact then the output would be/

Comment: The curious thing is... counting to one is one of the most precise experiments one can do. The only thing more precise than that is the case where absolutely nothing happens. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is an instantaneous notion; even on a curved trajectory at any moment you have a direction and a speed in that direction.  Each time you can calculate de derivative of position coordinates, you have a valid velocity.

Note that with your arguments you should say as well that positions don't exist and acceleration don't exist "because they change" ;-) .  If the argument feels wrong for position and acceleration, why should it feel right for velocity ?

Comment: Perhaps position,velocity,acceleration and jerk are all part of movement/change. But cannot exist on their own.

Comment: what do you mean by "to exist on their own" ? like the smile without the cat ? :-)

Comment: Sorry. I meant as an independent variable. The constant velocity of light ,since gravity/space can bend light, seems like it must have an acceleration component and in that way how can velocity be constant ?

Comment: Oh, you were not about the velocity vector of a moving solid, but about the (scalar) speed of light, which is a totally different mater, and your question seems indeed to be "how such thing like c could exist ?". If so, your question is totally missleading and you should rephrase it.

Comment: Anyway, when an object orbit circularly around another object, which means suffering acceleration vector and curved trajectory, it's speed is nevertheless constant.

Comment: Also, your are trying to understand things occuring at the speed of light using your intuition and Newton mechanics which stop to be valid at these speed. The best coherent analogy in Newton world would be to consider c is infinite: acceleration and addition can't change the infinite, a rocket would need infinite energy to reach c, etc.

Comment: And concerning velocity vector, indeed the "independant variable" is not the velocity, but inertia, i.e. linear momentum $m\vec v$ (for solids) or $\frac{h}{2\pi} \vec k$ for massless c-speed particules.

Comment: So when light was discovered to bend when passing the sun, is it then considered that light has an acceleration component since its been bent/changed direction ?

Comment: at that time the point was first to see that the light could be influenced by Sun gravity as a material object would. And Einstein way of seeing things was about space being curved by Sun mass. But yes, influence of gravity can be equivalently considered as causing a force (and thus an acceleration) or bending the space (and thus bending geodesics).

Comment: BTW don't forget that acceleration is a vector: it can be perpendicular to the path. Also, don't try to apply your low-speed intuitions of Euclidian mechanics to light-speed things: as for ultra-small scales of quantum mechanics, it occurs that the classical mechanics we are used to is indeed approximative and no longer accurate out of its range of scale and speed.

Answer (score -1):

The space time fabric is like a elastic/rubber sheet which can be twisted, elongated, etc. So this sheet is not straight because of depressions caused by massive objects (planets, stars, black holes).
 So when there is no disruption (twists, depression) in space time fabric, velocity is in straight line as the fabric is plane. But when there is a depression then there is acceleration towards it, hence there is no constant velocity.
So, straight/plain fabric - constant velocity, 
Disrupted fabric - increased or decreased velocity, due to external field/ force acting on it.